# Поддомен на отдельном сервере

Tags: домен, администрирование

Здравствуйте,

Арендую сервер, на котором висит домен, как можно модключить поддоме на другом сервере?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пропишите в dns вашего домена запись

```
subdomain    IN A 10.1.1.1*.subdomain    IN CNAME subdomain.mydomain.com.
```

где 10.1.1.1 - ip вашего второго сервера, а mydomain.com  - ваш домен.